# Reverse a nested array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm attempting to take a JSON API response, with nested associated resources, and reverse the associations in a Rails app.

So, imagine I get a response like this:

```
{
  "spenders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Account One"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Account Two"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Account One"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Account Three"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to convert this into structure like this:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Account One",
      "spenders": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stephen Margheim"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Greg Barendt"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Account Two",
      "spenders": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stephen Margheim"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Account Three",
      "spenders": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Greg Barendt"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I can do this fairly well with iteration over the hash and building a new hash:

```
spenders_hash = {}
accounts.each do |account|
  account.spenders.each do |spender|
    if spenders_hash.key? spender.id
      spenders_hash[spender.id][:accounts] << account
    else
      spenders_hash[spender.id] = hash_from_spender_and_account(spender, account)
    end
  end
end
spenders_hash

def hash_from_spender_and_account(spender, account)
  {
    id: spender.id,
    name: spender.name,
    accounts: [account],
  }
end
```

I'm hoping to find [1] a more flexible solution that isn't reliant on knowing the key names in advance and [2] hopefully more efficient.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you don't know the keys in advance, what do you know? For example, are looking for a key whose value is an array?

Comment: That there is a nested hash.

Comment: That is not clear, but in any event, you should edit the question rather than try to explain in comments.